# Call request animation frame every five seconds

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

If i need to get some new data constanly, i know that best solution is websockets.In that way the server will notify the client when there is new data. But to avoid this just for one scenario, i will need to call some http request on every five seconds.

I am using here counter just for simulation instead calling some http service.

```
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(counter);
  ++counter;
},5000)
```

I've read that better solution is requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval.It is more optimised by the browser and also when the tab is not active it is paused. Set interval continues to fire and when the tab is not active which is not good.

How can i call some function in requestAnimationFrame every five seconds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually only call it every 5 seconds, you'd still need (at least) `setTimeout`. But with this, something along the following would work:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(function run() {
    console.log('do something w/o initial delay');

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('do something w/ initial delay');

        requestAnimationFrame(run);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Tnx Yoshi for your response. I accepted your answer because it is working.Is this the only way with setTimeout recreation ?

Comment: @pece More or less. `requestAnimationFrame` has no timing function, because you'd normally want to call it as often as possible to ensure good fps (~60). If that's not your purpose, you need to work around that and only call it in intervals. Note that the code works, but I would probably never use `requestAnimationFrame` in that way. I'd stick to simple `setTimeout`s. Coincidentally you could replace  `requestAnimationFrame` with `setTimeout` in the above code without any change of behavior.